# Azure resource manager template HostingEnvironment

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I downloaded the arm template for Web App + MySQL from azure gallery:

[https://gallery.azure.com/artifact/...](https://gallery.azure.com/artifact/20151001/Microsoft.WebSiteMySQLDatabase.1.9.0/DeploymentTemplates/Website_NewHostingPlan_MySQL_NewDB.json)

and now trying to make a deployment using this. But I don't know/can't find out what values to supply for some parameters like HostingEnvironment, what are the accepted values, **where can I find them?**

I tried out "Free" and "Shared" for value, both are wrong.

```
    "ErrorEntity": {
            "Code": "NotFound",
            "Message": "Cannot find HostingEnvironment with name Shared.",
            "ExtendedCode": "51004",
            "MessageTemplate": "Cannot find {0} with name {1}.",
            "Parameters": [
               "HostingEnvironment",
               "Shared"
            ],
            InnerErrors": null
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The HostingEnvironment is the name of the [App Service Environment](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-app-service-environment-intro/). 
If you don't need it, try to leave it empty. Otherwise fork the template and remove the property.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know about the "hostingPlanName" variable?

Comment: That's just the name of the Hostingplan. When you click on the webapp in the portal you can find it with label "App Service plan/pricing tier"